# How to call function/method in parent view controller

Tags: objective-c, ios4

I have a MyViewController that has a UINavigationController as a subview and the UINavigatioController has a CustomView popped on the stack.  What I want to do is in the CustomView is to call a method in MyViewController.. so I tried this:

```
UINavigationController *main = (UINavigationController*)[self parentViewController];    
MyViewController *parentContainer = (MyViewController*)[main parentViewController];
[parentContainer myParentMethod];
```

this code is not correct.

Comment: I found this thread and it works great! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3370666/call-method-in-nested-parent-controllers

Answer (score 1):

The parentViewController property only works for the navigation controller, the tab bar controller, or in a modal presentation relationship. Although a MyViewController object has the view of a UINavigationController object as a subview, it doesn't mean that MyViewController is the parentViewController of the UINavigationController object.

If you have to keep this design and need to access the MyViewController object from a CustomView object, the best way of doing it is to let the CustomView object have a weak reference to the MyViewController object (like `delegate` properties).

Answer (score 0):

Define the following **macro** in your child .m

```
#define parentVC (\
(^UIViewController*(void){\
UIViewController *viewController = nil;\
for (UIView *next = [self isKindOfClass:[UIViewController class]]?[((UIViewController *)self).view superview]:[((UIView *)self) superview]; next; next = next.superview) {\
UIResponder *nextResponder = [next nextResponder];\
if ([nextResponder isKindOfClass:[UIViewController class]]) {\
viewController = (UIViewController *)nextResponder;\
break;\
}\
}\
return viewController;\
})()\
)
```

---

Then in your child-vc just cast said macro to parent class type and execute the method you want, like this:

`[(MyParentController *)parentVC myParentMethod];`